# What do we know about how open source software becomes eligible for the Docker Hub library?

Tags: docker, culture, open-source, images

Official community distros of well established open source software can be found in Docker Hub at the "special" place, the *library*, explicitely tagged as "official".

https://hub.docker.com/u/library/

How does it get there - by decision of Docker Inc., the company behind Docker, or is there some community application process?

For example, there is no such image for LaTeX.

Answers count referencing facts (no opinions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_repos/

> Docker, Inc. sponsors a dedicated team that is responsible for reviewing and publishing all content in the official repositories. This team works in collaboration with upstream software maintainers, security experts, and the broader Docker community. While it is preferable to have upstream software authors maintaining their corresponding Official Repositories, this is not a strict requirement.